# WebRTC using PeerJS - Will it work on Android & IOS apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webrtc, peerjs

We have been doing a WebRTC app using PeerJS for web.

Server side : NodeJS

Client side : HTML5/CSS/Javascript/Angularjs

We are 90% there and it is working fine in chrome firefox but not working in safari.I know that safari does not support WebRTC.

Is there **any workaround to make it work in safari like any plugin?**

**My second question is if i copy my web code and put it in phonegap or ionic will it work in Android and IOS .**
I mean for now we have done a chat using peerJS which is purely a javascript code will the chat work in phonegap or ionic apps in Android and IOS platform

Please share your ideas, which is greatly Appreciated.Thanks:-)

Comment: Its been One Year and no proper Answer to this question.  Really frustrating..

Answer (score 2):

**For first question**: There is a plugin to make WebRTC work on Safari (and IE). [You can check here to see the progress of PeerJS and the plugin](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/216)

**For second question**: You can do that with Android (for sure there is must be some modifications) but I do not think it work. But you can check [Crosswalk-project and PeerJS WebRTC library](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/webrtc.html)

Hope this help!